# SQL average multiple elements

Tags: sql, average, presto

How do I do this?

```
SELECT 
   AVG(t1, t2, t3) AS avg_3_hr
FROM table
```

SQL doesn't like multiple inputs to AVG

Comment: Can be done as + if that's what you need.

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Comment: [`avg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#avg) is aggregate function which does not make a lot of sense without `group by` clause of window function.

Comment: Simply `(t1 + t2 + t3) / 3.0 AS avg_3_hr`?

Answer (score 0):

SQL calculate the Average from a list on values on a column, this kind of function are called Aggregate.

Maybe you need to use other calculation like:

```
SELECT
   AVG(t1 + t2 + t3) AS avg_3_hr
FROM table
```

And get the AVG of the sum of 3 columns.

If you want to know more about SQL AVG function, check it: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-avg-function-introduction-and-examples/

Comment: This provides a wrong output, as long as `AVG(t1 + t2 + t3)` will be evaluated to `(t1 + t2 + 3)/n_rows`, where `n_rows = 1` if "*t1*", "*t2*" and "*t3*" are found in one single row under different columns (as it seems).

Comment: mmmm, I test it on https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/ using this code: 
    SELECT AVG(customer_id + age) AS id_age_avg FROM Customers;
This is a no sense query, but maybe, and just maybe is the answer for @jbuddy_13

Comment: By definition, *aggregation* functions (like `AVG`) do a simple thing: they *aggregate* rows. Given that this post has one row, attempting to use an aggregation function for this task does not follow sql nature. If really there was a correct answer for this problem, it was given in the comments section by jarlh.